# Using After Effects Expression To Script A Simple Shadow Behavior

Tags: javascript, animation, expression, 2d, after-effects

I'm working on an AE project where around 50 Emojis should have a drop shadow on the floor.To make things easier I tried to add an expression that auto shrinks and grows the shadows based on the distance of the emoji to the floor.

Here is what I've tried

[Drop Shadow Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVbJq.gif)

You can see  that the shadow grows and shrinks but in the wrong direction. So when emoji comes closer to the floor it shrinks and when the distance is more it grows. I need the opposite of the current behavior.

How do I achieve that?

This is the expression I've used for the **scale** property of the shadow layer. Shadow layer is separate from the emoji layer. So I have a composition with only 2 layers.

```
var y = thisComp.layer("smile").position[1];
var dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((this.position[0]-this.position[0]), 2) + Math.pow((this.position[1]-y), 2) );

newValue = dist ;
xScale = newValue;
yScale = newValue;
[xScale,yScale]
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept here is mapping values from one range to another. You want to say that (for example) as the distance changes between 0 and 100, the scale should change proportionally between 1 and 0.

```
function map ( x, oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax ) {
    return newMin + ( x - oldMin ) / ( oldMax - oldMin ) * ( newMax - newMin );
}

var minDistance = 0;
var maxDistance = 100;
var maxScale = 1;
var minScale = 0;
xScale = yScale = map( dist, minDistance, maxDistance, maxScale, minScale );
```

Comment: I think we are getting closer. However the shadow still grows / shrinks the wrong way. We do have more control over the shadow now which is awesome but do I need to make some modification to the code so the shadow works in the intended way? Thank you

Comment: Works correctly for me: distance 0 -> scale 1, distance 25 -> scale .75, distance 100 -> scale 0. So scale goes down as distance goes up. Check the order of your arguments maybe?

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen this guy is a hero :D Yea you were right I was doing wrong calculation for the dist variable. Problem is solved.

Comment: No worries. Save this function, it's got a million uses in animation.